# Extending covering projection of the boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ and $E$ be (topological) manifolds with boundaries $\partial M$ and $\partial E$ respectively and assume we have a finite-sheeted covering $\rho: \partial E\to \partial M$. Is it possible to find an extension $\tilde{\rho}:E\to M$ of $\rho$ which is a covering projection?

I am particularly interested in the case that $M$ and $E$ are $3$-dimensional manifolds and $\rho$ is $2$-sheeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not in general.  For instance, if $\partial M=\partial E$ and $\rho$ is the identity map, this would be saying that any two connected manifolds with the same boundary are homeomorphic.  This would imply that any two connected manifolds without boundary of the same dimension are homeomorphic, since you can remove a ball from each of them and get a homeomorphism, and then glue the ball back in.

[I am implicitly assuming here that you want the boundary to be nonempty and for $M$ and $E$ to be connected.  If you allow the boundary to be empty, you get that any manifold without boundary can cover any other, which is also certainly false.]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. Do you know anything about the other cases?

Comment: Well, this is just the simplest possible case.  The other cases will be similar.  If $\partial M$ and $M$ are connected and $\partial M\to M$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$, then any covering space of $\partial M$ extends uniquely to a covering space $\tilde{M}$ of $M$.  But there is no reason to expect that $E$ coincides with $\tilde{M}$, since $E$ can be any manifold at all with the same boundary as $\tilde{M}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see. What if $M=E$?

Comment: There's still no reason to think that just because $\partial M$ happens to be homeomorphic to one of its covering spaces, this covering extends to $M$ and $M$ is also homeomorphic to the extension.  For instance, if $M=D^2$ then $\partial M=S^1$ can cover itself in many ways, but only the trivial covering extends to $M$ because $M$ is simply connected.

Comment: Or if $M$ is $[0,\infty)\times S^1\times S^1$ with a closed ball removed, then $\partial M=S^1\times S^1$ can cover itself nontrivially and these covers extend to covers of $M$ since $\pi_1(\partial M)\to \pi_1(M)$ is an isomorphism, but the covers of $M$ are not homeomorphic to $M$ because they have multiple "copies" of the ball that was removed.